# How to scrape product details which is inbetween <div> tag using Xpath

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get the word BIBA. I am getting output like `\n,\n,\nBIBA,\n` But I only want "BIBA".
Please help me to get that name using xpath.

Thank you.

```
<div class="pdp-bname">
    <input type="hidden" value="/wishlist/getWishListData" `enter code here`id="miniWishlistFormActionUrl">
    <div class="prd-fav addToWishlist2">
        <form id="addToWishlistForm202180385_9607" class="wishlistPdpAddOrRemove" action="/wishlist/addOrRemoveWishlist/202180385_9607" method="POST"> <input type="hidden" value="5f49e2f4-9c05-4a5a-83b9-6edbc780cbe5" id="ajaxCSRF">
            <button type="submit" id="addwishlistId" class="go_link wishlistSubmitBtn wishlist ">
                 <!-- <label class="labletext">Add to wishlist</label> -->
            </button>
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" value="5f49e2f4-9c05-4a5a-83b9-6edbc780cbe5">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    "
    BIBA

    "
</div>
```

Comment: try to add `.strip('\n,')` after your command. I am guessing it will look something like this `item.xpath('your XPath selector').extract().strip('\n,'). If you can provide some more details like the code you already have, I can probably help more.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend to use [Scrapy Item Loaders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) and *[Input and Output processors](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#declaring-input-and-output-processors)*:

```
def strip_word(value):
    value = value.strip()
    return value

class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    my_word_field = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=TakeFirst(),
        output_processor=MapCompose(strip_word)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="pdp-bname"])')
```